# Batch file creating folder with time stamps creates space if time is < 10

Tags: batch-file

```
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
Set DateTime="R%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%"

mkdir %DateTime%
```

If the time is before 10:00AM, ie- R20140324_ 9-59 then a space is added after the underscore.  How can I get this to be a "0" so it is R20140324_09-59?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set DateTime="R%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%"
Set DateTime="%datetime: =0%"
echo mkdir %datetime%
```

`%var:string1=string2%` substitutes string2 for string1 in `var` rey to be assigned to the destination variable.

(mkdir simply `echo`ed for verification)

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir "%DateTime: =0%"
```

Just replace the space with a 0